# VS2010 link project output lib with dependence lib (without project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have solution with single project called Math.
The output of Math project is dll and import lib.
Math project uses another import lib (cxcore.lib) that is part of Math project files (was added as resource and its type was set to library).
My goal is that the linker will link cxcore.lib to math.lib so other projects that uses math.lib will not need to provide cxcore.lib to linker files.
I've set "link library dependencies" to "yes" but still cxcore.lib isn't linked to Math.lib.
As a work around I've used lib command (lib /out:x.lib mpsmath.lib cxcore.lib) as a post build event.
Is there any "clean" way to achieve this goal in VS2010 ?

Comment: I guess, if you link your "cxcore.lib" statically there is no need to add it to resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to "link" a .lib file into another .lib file you can't do that with MSVC: static libraries aren't linked. They are **intended to be linked against something**, but that doesn't mean linking happens when creating a .lib file.

You can either link your .lib file into the dll you're creating or move the source code of the dependency library (if you have it) into your project.